# Divide list element by another list element using a function or vba button

Tags: excel, list

I'm looking to learn how to create a function that's capable of dividing lists in excel. In python it can be done as shown.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dividing-two-lists/

The user entry is in the form of a cell of numbers separated by commas

i.e.:

```
cell a2: 12,86,71,54
cell b2: 1,3,2,1
```

This needs to be a function as it will require user input that will be dynamic. It can't be done with the text to columns function. For example, I have a user enter a list such as 12,86,71,54 which needs to be divided by another user entry of another comma separated list 1,3,2,1 (12/1 + 86/3 + 71/2 + 54/1)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function DivList(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String
    Dim arr1, arr2, arr3, i As Long

    arr1 = Split(s1, ",")
    arr2 = Split(s2, ",")
    ReDim arr3(LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1))

    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
         arr3(i) = arr1(i) / arr2(i)
    Next i
    DivList = Join(arr3, ",")
End Function
```

An example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you're awesome!